# Java - добавление компоненты в JPanel поверх другой компоненты

Tags: java, swing, gui, webbrowser, jpanel

В `JPanel` есть компонента [jWebBrowser](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html):

```
JPanel webPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
webPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Можно ли как-нибудь в `JPanel` добавить `JProgressBar` поверх компоненты браузера, чтобы во время, например, загрузки данных из базы данных, можно было бы оперировать `webBrowser.setVisible(false)` и `progressBar.setVisible(true)` для появления полосы загрузки и скрытия содержимого браузера?

В GUI не очень силен, такой код не помог:

```
    JProgressBar jP = new JProgressBar();
    JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
    ...
    final JPanel webPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    webPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    final JPanel jbarPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    jbarPanel.add(jP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //webPanel.add(jP, BorderLayout.CENTER); // пробовал сначала добавить все в одну JPanel
    add(webPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jbarPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите заменить один компонент на другой, то можно удалить из контейнера прежний компонент, и добавить другой, что-то вроде:

```java
remove(webPanel);
add(jbarPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
repaint(); // запросить перерисовку контейнера
```

Если нужно разместить один компонент над другим, можно воспользоваться [`javax.swing.JLayeredPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html). Она позволяет размещать компоненты на разных уровнях (задаются Integer, чем больше, тем выше). Можно разместить панель с браузером на нижнем уровне, а прозрачную панель с прогрессбаром на верхнем, и менять видимость верхней панели по мере необходимости.

```java
public class JLayeredPaneExample {

    static void initUi() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "JLayeredPaneExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        // Панель с содержимымы, поверх которого нужно будет выставлять прогрессбар
        JPanel background = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        background.add( new JTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER );
        background.add( new JButton("Button"), BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        // прозрачная панель с прогрессбаром по центру
        JPanel glasspane = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
        JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        glasspane.add( bar, new GridBagConstraints() );
        glasspane.setOpaque( false );
        // чтобы сквозь панель нельзя было кликнуть, ей задается слушатель
        glasspane.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {} );

        // создается JLayeredPane
        JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        // устанавливаем компоненты, чем больше второй параметр (номер слоя),
        //   тем "выше" компонент.
        // обратите внимание, что номер слоя должен быть объектом Integer
        //   поэтому используется либо метод с тремя параметрами и автобоксинг
        //   или приведение к Integer явно
        layeredPane.add( background, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER, -1 );
        layeredPane.add( glasspane, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER + 50, -1 );
        // JLayeredPane не содержит Layout (а если поставить, то layout будет
        //   выравнивать компоненты в одной плоскости, поэтому нужно задавать
        //   размеры и положение компонентов самостоятельно.
        //   В данном случае панелям ставится размер layeredpane.
        layeredPane.addComponentListener( new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                background.setSize( e.getComponent().getSize() );
                glasspane.setSize( e.getComponent().getSize() );
            }
        });

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        contentPane.add( layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        contentPane.add( new JButton( "Frame button" ), BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        frame.setContentPane( contentPane );

        Timer t = new Timer( 1000, (event) -> { 
            glasspane.setVisible( !glasspane.isVisible() );
            bar.setValue( bar.getValue() + 5 );
        } );
        t.start();


        frame.setSize( 800, 600 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( JLayeredPaneExample::initUi );
    }
}
```

Так же с Java 7 можно воспользоваться [`javax.swing.JLayer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayer.html), который можно навесить на любой компонент Swing, для рисования поверх или перехвата событий. Пример рисует по середине декорированного компонента слово "Загрузка" и блокирует получение компонентом событий мыши и клавиатуры:

```java
static class OverlayUi<V extends Component> extends LayerUI<V> {
    private boolean visible = false;
    private JLayer<?> layer;

    public void setVisible( boolean visible ) {
        this.visible = visible;
        if (layer != null) layer.repaint();            
    }

    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e, JLayer<? extends V> l) {
        if ( visible ) { // если оверлей виден, он перехватывает события
            if (e instanceof InputEvent) {
                ((InputEvent) e).consume();
            }
        } else {
            super.eventDispatched(e, l);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void installUI( JComponent c ) { // вызывается при установке
        super.installUI(c);
        layer = (JLayer<?>) c;
        layer.setLayerEventMask( // указываем события, которые хотим перехватывать
                AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | 
                AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK |
                AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK
            );
    }


    @Override
    public void paint( Graphics g, JComponent c ) {
        super.paint( g, c ); // отрисовка собственно компонента

        if ( !visible ) return; // если не виден, то ничего больше не рисует

        g.setFont( c.getFont().deriveFont( 20f ) );
        String text = "Загрузка...";
        Rectangle2D stringBounds = g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds( text, g );

        int x = (int)((c.getWidth() - stringBounds.getWidth())/2);
        int y = (int)((c.getHeight() - stringBounds.getHeight())/2);
        g.drawString( text, x, y );
    }
}

// использование в предыдущем примере:
OverlayUi<JPanel> overlayUi = new OverlayUi();
JLayer<JPanel> panelOverlay = new JLayer<JPanel>(background, overlayUi ); 
contentPane.add( panelOverlay, BorderLayout.CENTER );

overlayUi.setVisible( true );
```

В [обучалке](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) на сайте Oracle есть пример с анимированым индикатором загрузки.