# Помогите советом по swing

Tags: java, swing

Пару месяцев изучаю java и решил запилить морской бой где игровое поле это панель с кнопками 10х10. Подскажите способ делать такую панель не активной т е с неактивными кнопками на время хода одного из игроков

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, есть следующие способы решения проблемы (в порядке усложнения):

1. В цикле вызвать у всех нужных кнопок `setEnabled`. Кнопки можно хранить в какой-то коллекции или массиве, или разместить в отдельном контейнере (`JPanel`, например) и воспользоваться его методом `Component[] Container.getComponents()`.
2. Декорировать игровое поле (панель с кнопками) с помощью `JLayer` и перехватывать в нем события мыши и клавиатуры. Это позволит что-нибудь нарисовать поверх заблокированного игрового поля. Если сверху захочется разместить другие компоненты swing, то вместо `JLayer` можно использовать `JLayeredPane` ([мой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484381/190934) к другому вопросу).
3. Отказаться от кнопок и рисовать игровое поле самому. Понадобится обрабатывать события мыши и т.п.

Пример реализации первых двух способов с комментариями в коде:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class SwingDisableButtons {

    // т.к. примера два, общая часть (создание кнопок и установка слушателей)
    // вынесена в абстрактный класс.
    static abstract class GamePanel extends JPanel {
        static final int GRID_SIZE = 20;

        public GamePanel() {
            setLayout( new GridLayout( GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE ) );
            for ( int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; row++ ) {
                for ( int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; col++ ) {
                    JButton btn = new JButton( String.format( "%dx%d", col, row ) );
                    btn.addActionListener( makeListener( row, col ) );
                    add( btn );
                }
            }
        }

        ActionListener makeListener( int row, int col ) {
            return event -> onButtonClick( event, row, col );
        }

        void onButtonClick( ActionEvent event, int row, int col ) {
            System.out.printf( "button at r: %d, c: %d click.%n", row, col );
        }

        /**
         * Устанавливает доступность игрового поля.
         * 
         * @param enabled
         */
        public abstract void setFieldEnabled( boolean enabled );

        /**
         * Возвращает компонент для установки в интерфейс
         * 
         * @return
         */
        // это не обязательно, но поскольку я запихал JLayer внутрь следующего класса,
        // то его надо будет отдавать наружу, для вставки во фрейм
        public abstract JComponent getUi();
    }

    static class GamePanelWithSetEnabled extends GamePanel {
        @Override
        public void setFieldEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            RepaintManager manager = RepaintManager.currentManager( this );
            // getComponents() возвращает все дочерние компоненты этой панели.
            // поскольку на ней одни кнопки, то можно включать/выключать все подряд
            for ( Component c : getComponents() ) {
                c.setEnabled( enabled );
                // использование RepaintManager позволяет избежать эффекта
                // постепенного отключения
                // вызов сообщает менеджеру, что компонент перерисовывать не надо 
                manager.markCompletelyClean( (JComponent)c );
            }
            // запрашиваем перерисовку для всей панели разом
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public JComponent getUi() {
            return this;
        }
    }

    static class GamePanelWithJLayer extends GamePanel {
        // класс оверлея, который будет рисоваться поверх нашей кнопочной панели
        // и заодно перехватывать события мыши и клавиатуры, когда активен.
        static class OverlayUi<V extends Component> extends LayerUI<V> {
            // признак видимости оверлея
            private boolean visible = false;
            private JLayer<?> layer;

            public void setVisible( boolean visible ) {
                this.visible = visible;
                if (layer != null) layer.repaint();            
            }

            // перехватчик событий
            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e, JLayer<? extends V> l) {
                if ( visible ) {
                    // если оверлей виден, не пропускаем пришедшее событие к панели
                    if (e instanceof InputEvent) {
                        ((InputEvent) e).consume();
                    }
                } else {
                    super.eventDispatched(e, l);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void installUI( JComponent c ) {
                super.installUI(c);
                layer = (JLayer<?>) c;
                // задаем маску событий, которые оверлей должен перехватывать
                layer.setLayerEventMask( 
                        AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | 
                        AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK |
                        AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK
                    );
            }

            // отрисовка оверлея. Заливает все полупрозрачным серым
            // и выводит поверх надпись "Ждите..."
            // В официальной обучалке показаны более интересные вещи, например
            // размытие: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html#drawing
            //   (см. BlurLayerUI)
            @Override
            public void paint( Graphics g, JComponent c ) {
                super.paint( g, c );

                if ( !visible ) return;

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
                g2d.setColor( new Color( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f ) );
                g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight() );

                g2d.setFont( c.getFont().deriveFont( 20f ) );
                g2d.setColor( Color.ORANGE );
                String text = "Ждите...";
                Rectangle2D stringBounds = g2d.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds( text, g2d );

                double x = (c.getWidth() - stringBounds.getWidth())/2;
                double y = (c.getHeight() - stringBounds.getHeight())/2;
                g2d.drawString( text, (float)x, (float)y );

                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setFieldEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            if ( myJLayer != null ) {
                myOverlayUi.setVisible( !enabled );
            }
        }

        JLayer<GamePanelWithJLayer> myJLayer;
        OverlayUi<GamePanelWithJLayer> myOverlayUi;

        // нужно вернуть JLayer для вставки во фрейм
        @Override
        public JLayer<GamePanelWithJLayer> getUi() {
            if ( myJLayer == null ) {
                myOverlayUi = new OverlayUi<>();
                myJLayer = new JLayer<>( this, myOverlayUi );
            }

            return myJLayer;
        }
    }

    static void initUi() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "test" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        // на выбор:
        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanelWithSetEnabled();
        //GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanelWithJLayer();

        JPanel content = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        content.add( gamePanel.getUi(), BorderLayout.CENTER );

        JButton button = new JButton( "click me!" );
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            boolean enabled = true;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                enabled = !enabled;
                gamePanel.setFieldEnabled( enabled );
            }
        });

        content.add( button, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        frame.setContentPane( content );
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( SwingDisableButtons::initUi );
    }
}
```

Comment: ого, вот это ответ =)   большое спасибо ! Всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625878

```
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
     }
   }
);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я так понимаю придется указывать каждой из ста кнопок метод setEnabled()  =)  хотелось что то более изящное

Comment: @Пустота если кнопки не меняют внешнего вида, то можно сделать где-нибудь доступную переменную, которая определяет, чей ход, и при нажатии на кнопку проверять допустимость действия.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был признателен вам за ваш комментарий.