# Java Swing. Запретить пользователю нажатие на кнопку, но при этом оставить ее активной

Tags: java, swing

Добавить поверх невидимую панель - не вариант, так как кнопка в таком случае все равно будет доступна для нажатия. Мне же нужно чтобы нажимать можно было только программно (doClick()), а пользователь этого делать не мог. Какие есть варианты?

Comment: Кто-то еще программирует под swing? Зачем JavaFX, если ты хардкорщик и любишь устаревшие технологии.

Comment: button.setEnabled(false); чем не подходит ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator для кнопок уже заданы неактивные иконки, теперь понимаю что с самого начала нужно было реализовывать по-другому. 
Не хотелось бы под ии переписывать все с нуля.

Сделал хитро, но, наверное, не оптимально - удалил все обработчики, а перед каждым вызовом doClick этот слушатель добавляю.

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин ну, я учусь пока что и реализацию игры на Swing выбрал в качестве самостоятельной, JavaFX буду осваивать

Comment: @user193688 я так и не понял почему не можешь

Comment: можно компоненты в JLayer [заворачивать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506911/190934), и в нем перехватывать события мыши.